# Polldaddy plugin - WordPress

Tags: wordpress, plugins

Anyone knows how to remove text at the end of the poll ("Create your own free online surveys now! Powered by Polldaddy"). Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken directly from their website:

> How do I remove the Polldaddy.com link from my poll or survey?
>   The link to Polldaddy.com only appears in polls and surveys that appear in a free account. They are removed from all content in both our Pro and Corporate accounts. If you have recently signed up for a Pro account and the link has remained in your polls, simple edit and re-save the poll to remove it.

Comment: but maybe there is an option to make change in code?

Comment: That would be illegal. You could attempt to modify the plugin, but that is not recommended. If PollDaddy iFrames the polls in then there is no way to do it.